# How do I run python code that I've crawled through a page in the same run

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler

I was going through some of the thenewboston's python tutorials, building a web crawler, to name one. He puts the code for each tutorial on his forum. I wanted to crawl through the page in the forum and get the code and save it in a file and run the file.

Python program->Crawling forum, searching for code->Saving the code to a file->Running that file->Ending the main python program.

Comment: Can you please show your code that you have tried?

Comment: Beware that running code from internet may be armful. Be sure from the origin of the code you want to run!

Comment: In simple terms, Python program that runs a python file inside it that it just created. How do I go about doing that?